# .htaccess combined rules (redirect non-ssl to ssl AND exections)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Basically I have 2 different rules/tasks which should be combined in one working set of rule.

**Task 1**

All non-ssl pages have to be redirected to ssl. My solution is already working on its own.

Dummy example:

non-ssl://sample.some-website.ch/de/test.html -> ssl://sample.some-website.ch/de/test.html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sample.some-website.ch$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/sample\.some\-website\.ch\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

**Task 2**

All old .phtml Links have to be redirected to new SSL pages (individually). My solution is working on its own (2 dummy examples)

non-ssl://sample.some-website.ch/xyz.phtml -> ssl://sample.some-website.ch/de/newlink.html
non-ssl://sample.some-website.ch/123.phtml -> ssl://sample.some-website.ch/en/something.html

```
redirect 301 /xyz.phtml https://sample.some-website/de/newlink.html
redirect 301 /123.phtml https://sample.some-website.ch/en/something.html
```

**Problem**

I need a .htaccess solution which combines Task 1 and Task 2.
Certain old .phtml (non ssl) links have to redirected to new specific SSL-Pages **AND** all 'other normal' non-ssl links have to be automatically redirected to its corresponsing SSL-pages.
In the end only ssl-pages are displayed.

Any ideas?
Thanks. Hans.

Comment: Can you show your complete .htaccess?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kn3mtgwe2y7zahc/htaccess-code.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /

# redirect old links
RewriteRule ^xyz\.phtml$ https://sample.some-website/de/newlink.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^123\.phtml$ https://sample.some-website.ch/en/something.html  [L,R=301]

# add https to your site
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# route .html file to index.php    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .*\.html$ index.php [L]

# earlier rules to rewrite to index.php    
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})?/$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})?)$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Excellent solution.
To force always www I added the following rules:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sample.some-website.ch$
RewriteRule .* https://sample.some-website.ch%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]